# Windows Phone Launcher/Theme

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-themes

I want to ask that is there way for creating Themes or Launcher for windows phone.Because when i search over the internet it leads me to the launcher and pickers (Browser launcher, Contact Picker) etc. i have created several themes for windows 7+ which are working fine and now i want to create same for the windows phone. All i need is to change the default icons,sounds,background images .
If windows phone does not have such facilities then you can also tell me if this can be done pragmatically.

Any help is Appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Microsoft do not provide core accessibility (OS level access) to 3rd party developers. That's the reason why `Themes` can not be developed for windows phone.

So, answer to your question is **NO, you can't develop Themes for Windows Phone**

> **alternative through Launchers**

I saw 2-3 apps in wp store which was nicely programmed to run like a Theme.

- make an app in which you use all available In-built OS reserved launchers and Settings launchers. check [This Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207065(v=vs.105).aspx) & [This Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx) for detailed info on Launchers available.
- After making this kind of `Launcher` app, provide user with a tutorial screen in which ask user to set this app (only this app) in `Apps Corner` and then Launch the apps Corner.

> **To experience this live, i suggest look [This Application](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/kitkat-launcher/bfa60d3b-b2ab-47f8-ab69-e0a84ddfa8f3)**

Hope this will help..!